# Subsequential limits and adherent points

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

For a given sequence, I want to prove that the set of its subsequential limits contains all of its adherent points. 
(Note: Here, both the positive and negative infinities are excluded.)

My idea is that basically my first step is to prove that for an given adherent point x of the sequence, x is a part of S.

So, how can I approach such proof? And what’s next? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of adherent point of a sequence?

Comment: Let S be a set of R, and x belongs to R. We say that x is an adherent point of S if for all e>0, we have (x-e, x+e) Intersect S not empty.

Comment: That's for set, yes. But for a sequence? $1,2,2,2,2,2,\ldots$ has $1$ as an adherent point of $\{x_n: n \in \omega\} = \{1,2\}$ but it isn't one for the *sequence* (no subsequential limit to it).

Comment: Every limit of a sequence $S$ is clearly adherent to $S$ and every sub-sequence is a sequence. For example, for the sequence $\{1/n+ 1/m\}_{m,n}$  all $1/n$ whit $n\gt 0$ is a limit of a sub-sequence of $S$ but the limit of $S$ is $0$